# Access 2007 updateable query

Tags: sql, ms-access

This query is driving me crazy today.

I'm using Access 2007 and for some reason this query is not updateable. I'm using linked tables to a SQL Server DB, and all of the tables in the query have primary keys.

If I remove the tblCustTerms table and references to its tables I can update the query, so I guess that's where the problem is. However, I'm joining it on CustID (which could have more than one row in tblCustTerms) and DirectShipOrWarehouse = "Warehouse" (that, when combined with the CustId, will result in no more than a single record). If this is the problem (as I slightly suspect), what could I do to fix it?

Thanks!!

```
SELECT tblInventoryInvoices.ID, tblInventoryInvoices.SelectInvoice, 
  (tblInventoryInvoices.CTIPONUM & "." & tblInventoryInvoices.InvoiceSequence) AS CTIPONUM,
  tblInventoryInvoices.CustIDToInvoice AS CustID,
  tblInventoryInvoices.LocIDToInvoice AS LocID,
  tblOrders.DirectShiporWarehouse, tblInventoryInvoices.ERPExportDate AS InvoiceExportDate,
  tblInventoryInvoices.InvoiceSentDate, tblOrders.CustPO, tblItems.ItemDescription,
  tblCustTerms.qbTermsName, tblCustTerms.DirectShipOrWarehouse
FROM (tblInventoryInvoices INNER JOIN ((tblOrderDetail INNER JOIN tblItems ON 
  tblOrderDetail.ItemID = tblItems.ItemID) INNER JOIN tblOrders
  ON tblOrderDetail.CTIPONum = tblOrders.CTIPONum) ON tblInventoryInvoices.LineNumber = 
  tblOrderDetail.LineNumber) AND (tblInventoryInvoices.CTIPONUM =
  tblOrderDetail.CTIPONum)) INNER JOIN tblCustTerms ON
  tblInventoryInvoices.CustIDToInvoice = tblCustTerms.CustID
WHERE (((tblInventoryInvoices.ERPExportDate) Is Not Null)
   AND ((tblInventoryInvoices.InvoiceSentDate) Is Null) 
   AND ((tblOrders.CustPO)<>"ZPO") 
   AND ((tblCustTerms.DirectShipOrWarehouse)="Warehouse"))
ORDER BY (tblInventoryInvoices.CTIPONUM & "." & tblInventoryInvoices.InvoiceSequence), 
   tblInventoryInvoices.CustIDToInvoice, tblInventoryInvoices.LocIDToInvoice;
```

Comment: Have you tried setting your query Recordset Type property to Dynaset(Inconsistent Updates) instead of Dynaset?

Comment: That worked! I could have sworn I'd already tried that. I guess I must have tinkered with the query since then. Thanks!